# Image not loading in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-image

Trying to load image in flutter but not able to do that, getting following error

> I/flutter ( 3214): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE
>   ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════ I/flutter (
>   3214): The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
>   I/flutter ( 3214): Unable to load asset: assets/test.jpg I/flutter (
>   3214):  I/flutter ( 3214): When the exception was thrown, this was the
>   stack: I/flutter ( 3214): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load
>   (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7) I/flutter (
>   3214):  I/flutter ( 3214): #1
>   AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync
>   (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:429:44) I/flutter (
>   3214):  I/flutter ( 3214): #2
>   AssetBundleImageProvider.load
>   (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:414:14) I/flutter (
>   3214): #3      ImageProvider.resolve.. (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:267:86)
>   I/flutter ( 3214): #4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent
>   (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:143:20) I/flutter (
>   3214): #5      ImageProvider.resolve.
>   (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:267:63) I/flutter (
>   3214): (elided 8 frames from package dart:async) I/flutter ( 3214): 
>   I/flutter ( 3214): Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name:
>   "assets/test.jpg") I/flutter ( 3214): Image key:
>   AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#81de5(), name:
>   "assets/test.jpg", scale: I/flutter ( 3214): 1.0) I/flutter ( 3214):

main.dart

```
lass MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('EasyList'),
    ),
    body: Card(child: Column(children: < Widget > [
      Image.asset('assets/test.jpg'),
    ],),),
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

assets:
  - assets/test.jpg
```

Comment: The indentation above is incorrect. Check that there are space in front of `uses..` etc.

Comment: @RichardHeap space is there in pubspace.yaml file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need two spaces in front of the word `assets:` and two additional spaces in front of the dash (for a total of 4).

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/test.jpg
```

Answer (score 4):

Or if your are Using Android Studio IDE then in your `pubspec.yaml` file simply press
 <kbd>CTRL+ALT+L</kbd> to rearrange code . And then click packages get .